# Pattern matching against URL with question mark in Scala

Tags: scala

I am trying to extract few values from the URL consisting of question mark.

However, the below code doesn't work. Would you please help me in figuring out what went wrong?

```
val LibraryPattern = ".*/library/([A-Za-z0-9\\-]+)?book=([A-Za-z0-9\\-]+)".r
val url = "https://bookscollection.com/library/mylib?book=abc"
  Try(new URL(url)) match {
    case Success(url) =>
      println("my url:"+url)
      url.getPath match {
        case LibraryPattern(libId, bookId) =>

          println(libId)
          println(bookId)
        case _ =>
      }
  }
```

Comment: I love how everyone is changing their answers when they realise that the problem is `getPath` not the regex.

Comment: I wonder if they never tried to just check code in repl.

Comment: Can't you do url.getQuery and parse that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As few answer already pointed how to fix code example, I want to suggest another solution. Parsing URL with regex may be inefficient in terms of future readability, type safety and flexability of your codebase.

I want to suggest using [scala-uri library](https://github.com/lemonlabsuk/scala-uri) or something similar.

With this library one can do url parsing as simple as:

```
import io.lemonlabs.uri.Url 

val url = Url.parse("https://bookscollection.com/library/mylib?book=abc") 
val lastPathPart = url.path.parts.last 
// println(lastPathPart)
// res: String = "mylib"
val bookParam: Option[String] = url.query.param("book")
// println(bookParam)
// res: Option[String] = Some("abc")
```

Answer (score 2):

[`?` is a special character in Regex](https://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html) (it essentially makes the previous character/group optional). You'll need to escape it.

**EDIT**: `url.getPath` only returns `/library/mylib`, so you shouldn't use this if you want your Regex to match.

```
val LibraryPattern = ".*/library/([A-Za-z0-9\\-]+)\\?book=([A-Za-z0-9\\-]+)".r
val url = "https://bookscollection.com/library/mylib?book=abc"
Try(new URL(url)) match {
  case Success(url) =>
    println("my url:"+url)
    url.toString match {
      case LibraryPattern(libId, bookId) =>
        println(libId)
        println(bookId)
      case _ =>
    }
}
```

Comment: pattern didn't match, so libId, bookId are not extracted

Comment: `url.getPath` returns `/library/mylib` so it would never have matched anyway. I thought you were aware of this. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The `URL` object has already parsed the URL for you. `getPath` returns everything before the `?`, use `getQuery` to obtain the part after the `?`:

```
 val LibraryPattern = ".*/library/([A-Za-z0-9\\-]+)".r
 val BookPattern = "book=([A-Za-z0-9\\-]+)".r
 val url = "https://bookscollection.com/library/mylib?book=abc"
 Try(new URL(url)) match {
   case Success(url) =>
     url.getPath match {
       case LibraryPattern(libId) =>
         url.getQuery match {
           case BookPattern(bookId) =>
             println(libId)
             println(bookId)
         }
     }
 }
```